# SQL select instance in table if it does no longer exist with later year value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

The following table structure is given:

| year | team_ID | team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 1 | Manchester |
| 2011 | 2 | Bayern |
| 2011 | 3 | Madrid |
| 2012 | 1 | Manchester |
| 2012 | 2 | Bayern |
| 2012 | 4 | Chelsea |

The Objective is to select the teams that were in the table in the year 2011 but got kicked out for the year 2012.
In this case only Madrid has the year 2011 but not 2012, so it would be the only one selected.


The expected output is:

| team |
| --- |
| Madrid |

Thank you for your help!

Comment: use a sub-query with [not exists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a correlated `exists`, such as

```
select team
from t
where year=2011
and not exists (select * from t t2 where t2.year = 2012 and t2.team = t.team);
```

Comment: "That got kicked out in 2012", so i would change `year !=t.year` to `year = 2012`

Comment: Good catch I misread that :)